# Undefined Function Error PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm writing a class and I can't figure out why I am getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Directory::BuildDirectoryListing() 
in C:\www\directory.php on line 25
```

It doesn't make any sense. By the error it looks like it is trying to look for a static function. Here is the code I am using:

```
$odata = new Directory($listing['id']);
$adata = $odata->BuildDirectoryListing();

<?php

include_once("database.php");

class Directory {

    public $listing = array();
    public $aacategories = array();

    function __construct($_listing) {

        $this->listing = $_listing;

    }

    public function BuildDirectoryListing() {

        /* function code here */

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: "Directory" is a reserved class in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php

Comment: I'm not sure why that is a "-1".  It seems like anyone could have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directory](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directory.php) is a PHP built-in class.

You need to `namespace` your code or change your class name:

Class:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

class Directory {

    public $listing = array();
    public $aacategories = array();

    function __construct($_listing) {

        $this->listing = $_listing;

    }

    public function BuildDirectoryListing() {

        /* function code here */

    }

}

?>
```

Creating the class:

```
<?php

$odata = new \MyApp\Directory($listing['id']);
$adata = $odata->BuildDirectoryListing();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a static function in `Directory::BuildDirectoryListing()`, change this line

```
public function BuildDirectoryListing() {
```

for

```
public static function BuildDirectoryListing() {
```